# Is .jar archive not anymore useful if I need to apply a patch to a library?

Tags: java, jar

I've downloaded Lucene jar file. I'm including it in my classpath to run my Lucene application.

However, I now need to apply a patch. Should I download the Lucene sources, apply the patch and compile.. right ? I cannot use anymore the jar...

thanks

ps. I also need to know how to apply patches in java actually... what's the command from terminal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *may* be alternative approaches, but creating a completely new jar file would be your best bet, IMO. It'll be a lot harder to mess up with subtle issues than providing a second jar file to take priority for just *some* classes, etc.

Comment: ok, so I'm going to download source files. And by the way, how do I apply the patch ? Is there a command for that ?

Comment: @Patrick: It depends on what operating system you're using, what form the patch takes etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm right but in my opinion to apply the patch your corrected classes have to appear on the class path before the incorrect ones. So you can make a jar containing corrected classes and put it somewhere on the class path earlier than the original lucene jar.

Comment: ok, by the way, how do I apply the patch ? I added this to the question.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add a class or update an existing one, you'll use the same jar command but with that -u option. try `jar -help` from the terminal.

Comment: but in the jar file there are only .class files I don't get how the patch can update the code.

Comment: @Patrick, by patch i'm assuming either .class files or .java files. If you got .java files, you'll compile them using appropriate classpath and update the jar with those class files.

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet is correct -- creating a new jar is the best thing to do. You *can* just put the directory tree containing the new `.class` files on your classpath before the old jar file, but that's messy and error-prone.

To apply the patch, use the command `patch -p<n> <patch_file.txt` in the root directory of the source.

where `<n>` is the number of directories to strip from the pathnames in the patch to match the pathnames in the source tree -- start with 0.

Comment: uhm thanks. I've just run this: patch -p0 LUCENE-2236.patch from the root folder of my sources but nothing happens.. I don't see error message either.. any tip ? (5 minutes waiting.. and it is not a huge library)

Comment: @tvadies in the patch I can see this line: Index: lucene/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanWeight.java
So my working directory is the parent folder of "lucene", and the patch is also there.

Comment: redirect standard input of the patch command from the file -- `patch -p0 <LUCENE-2236.patch`